# Comparing two vectors in an if statement

Tags: r, loops, operators, dataframe

I want put stop condition inside a function. The condition is that if first and second elements should match perfectly in order and length.

```
A <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
B <- A
C <- c("A", "C", "C", "E")

> A == B
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

This is good situation to go forward

```
> A == C

[1]  TRUE  FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Since there is one false this condition to stop and output that the condition doesnot hold at 2 and 4 th column.

```
if (A != B) {
           stop("error the A and B does not match at column 2 and 4"} else {
            cat ("I am fine") 
                }
Warning message:
In if (A != B) (stop("error 1")) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Am I missing something obvious ? Also I can output where error positions are ?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`all` is one option:

```
> A <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
> B <- A
> C <- c("A", "C", "C", "E")

> all(A==B)
[1] TRUE
> all(A==C)
[1] FALSE
```

But you may have to watch out for recycling:

```
> D <- c("A","B","A","B")
> E <- c("A","B")
> all(D==E)
[1] TRUE
> all(length(D)==length(E)) && all(D==E)
[1] FALSE
```

The documentation for `length` says it currently only outputs an integer of length 1, but that it may change in the future, so that's why I wrapped the length test in `all`.

Comment: Your caution about recycling is why you should use `isTRUE(all.equal(D,E))`.

Comment: Looking at the code for `all.equal.character` was enlightening to me.  Because of the "near-equality" aspect of it for floats I'd assumed it did something funny for other things too.  I'm not sure what, in retrospect. But the only perhaps unwanted thing it does is to check for equality of all the attributes, including names.  It also takes more care with `NA`s than my simple code above does.

Answer (score 35):

Are they identical?

```
> identical(A,C)
[1] FALSE
```

Which elements disagree:

```
> which(A != C)
[1] 2 4
```

Comment: `identical` also compares attributes, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: No attributes are present here, but that's an important point.  Thanks.

Comment: `all.equal` also compares attributes, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

I'd probably use `all.equal` and `which` to get the information you want. It's not recommended to use `all.equal` in an `if...else` block for some reason, so we wrap it in `isTRUE()`. See `?all.equal` for more:

```
foo <- function(A,B){
  if (!isTRUE(all.equal(A,B))){
    mismatches <- paste(which(A != B), collapse = ",")
    stop("error the A and B does not match at the following columns: ", mismatches )
  } else {
    message("Yahtzee!")
  }
}
```

And in use:

```
> foo(A,A)
Yahtzee!
> foo(A,B)
Yahtzee!
> foo(A,C)
Error in foo(A, C) : 
  error the A and B does not match at the following columns: 2,4
```

Comment: The reason is that when they're not equal it doesn't return `FALSE` but a description of how they differ.

Comment: @Aaron - yes indeed. The help page for `?identical` gives some more insight on this...(which i perused after posting)