# is `vec` same as `rollapply(vec, width = 1, by = 1, FUN = mean, align = "left")`?

Tags: r

I have vector from which I've created subset using this command:

```
sub.as = as[seq(70,100)]
```

The subset is following:

```
> is.vector(sub.as)
[1] TRUE

> str(sub.as)
 num [1:31] 1 0.75 0.9 0.475 0.925 0.975 1 1 0.525 1 ...

> sub.as
 [1] 1.000 0.750 0.900 0.475 0.925 0.975 1.000 1.000 0.525 1.000 0.200 0.200
[13] 0.200 0.200 0.150 0.150 0.150 0.150 0.150 0.450 0.875 0.175 0.150 0.150
[25] 0.150 0.100 0.100 0.100 0.100 0.350 1.000
```

I've applied `rollapply` to this vector following way:

```
> sub.as.avg.1 = rollapply(sub.as, width = 1,  by = 1,  FUN = mean, align = "left")
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374932/comparing-two-vectors-in-an-if-statement) answer I've compared both vectors. Length of the outputs are the same:

```
> length(sub.as)
[1] 31

> length(sub.as.avg.1)
[1] 31
```

Values on those indexes should be different:

```
> which(sub.as != sub.as.avg.1)
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
```

Values that should be different (but as you can see they aren't):

```
> sub.as[which(sub.as != sub.as.avg.1)]
 [1] 0.200 0.200 0.200 0.200 0.150 0.150 0.150 0.150 0.150 0.450 0.175 0.150
[13] 0.150 0.150 0.100 0.100 0.100 0.100

> sub.as.avg.1[which(sub.as != sub.as.avg.1)]
 [1] 0.200 0.200 0.200 0.200 0.150 0.150 0.150 0.150 0.150 0.450 0.175 0.150
[13] 0.150 0.150 0.100 0.100 0.100 0.100
```

Questions:

1. is `vec` same as `rollapply(vec, width = 1,  by = 1, FUN = mean, align
   = "left")`?
2. Why `which` shows that there are differences between vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the difference between the two `rollapply` codes below.  The first uses `mean` and the second uses `(mean)`.  If `rollapply` senses that the code is trying to take means then it uses a faster algorithm and that involves computation which can result in small numeric differences.  [In an offline discussion Achim pointed out that this optimization is faster even with `width = 1`.)  On the other hand, if `(mean)` is used then that defeats its attempt to recognize that means are desired and the optimization is not applied and so there are no numeric differences (although it will be slower).

```
library(zoo)

sub.as <- c(1, 0.75, 0.9, 0.475, 0.925, 0.975, 1, 1, 0.525, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 
 0.2, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.45, 0.875, 0.175, 0.15, 
 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 1)
```

First

```
# 1
r1 <- rollapply(sub.as, width = 1,  by = 1, FUN = mean, align = "left")
sub.as - r1
##  [1]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
##  [6]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
## [11]  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17
## [16]  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17
## [21]  0.000000e+00 -2.775558e-17 -2.775558e-17 -2.775558e-17 -2.775558e-17
## [26] -2.775558e-17 -2.775558e-17 -2.775558e-17 -2.775558e-17  0.000000e+00
## [31]  0.000000e+00
```

Second

```
# 2
r2 <- rollapply(sub.as, width = 1, by = 1, FUN = (mean), align = "left")
identical(sub.as, r2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**Updated:**  Have revised answer to correspond to revision in question.

Comment: The question is why `mean` over one number (`width = 1,  by = 1`) should give another value than it was before. This does not make sense.