# Passing function in round brackets from variable to rollapply

Tags: r, function

You can pass function (in this example `mean`) to `rollapply` at least in two different ways (note round brackets in 2nd example) as it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165486/is-vec-same-as-rollapplyvec-width-1-by-1-fun-mean-align-left):

```
> sub.as.avg.1 <- rollapply(sub.as, width = 1,  by = 1,  FUN = mean,   align = "left")
> sub.as.avg.1 <- rollapply(sub.as, width = 1,  by = 1,  FUN = (mean), align = "left")
```

Now I want to pass function from variable. This one is working:

```
> fun
[1] "mean"
> r2 <- rollapply(sub.as, width = 1, by = 1, FUN = (fun), align = "left")
>
```

But this one is not:

```
> fun
[1] "(mean)"
> r2 <- rollapply(sub.as, width = 1, by = 1, FUN = fun, align = "left")
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object '(mean)' of mode 'function' was not found
```

How to make this work? What does round brackets mean for `rollapply`? Are they `rollapply` specific or it is something general to R?

**EDIT:**
Based on @DavidGo answer I've tried following:

```
library(zoo)

sub.as <- c(1, 0.75, 0.9, 0.475, 0.925, 0.975, 1, 1, 0.525, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 
 0.2, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.45, 0.875, 0.175, 0.15, 
 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 1)

my.func <- function(x, fun){
  result.vec <- rollapply(x, width = 1, by = 1, FUN = fun, align = "left")
  result.vec
}

r1 <- my.func(sub.as, mean)
r2 <- my.func(sub.as, (mean))
```

But it seems like if I were using `(mean)` in both cases:

```
> sub.as - r1
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> sub.as - r2
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> identical(sub.as, r1)
[1] TRUE
> identical(sub.as, r2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Use the `eval(parse` if you really want to go that route. i.e. `rollapply(sub.as, width = 1, by = 1, FUN = eval(parse(text=fun)), align = "left")`

Comment: Please check the updated comment.  BTW, it should work for both `fun`s

Comment: Why are you passing `"(mean)"`? If you want ensure that the optimization of calling `rollmean` is not used and pass the function dymically, just pass the default S3 method `"mean.default"`. `rollapply` checks if `mean` has been passed by using `deparse(substitute(FUN))`. Like this: `fun <- function(FUN) {
  deparse(substitute(FUN))
}; fun((mean))`. You can reproduce the error you are seeing like this: `match.fun("(mean)")`.

Comment: If you pass a character string or an expression that evaluates to a character string to the `FUN=` argument of `rollapply` then that character string must contain the name of the function you want to use.  There is no function named `(mean)`.  Note that if you do pass a character string to `rollapply` it will not call `rollmean` so there is no point in parenthesizing a character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you initialize fun like this: `fun = "(mean)"` while in the example you provided it is a closure. If you want to stick to the example you could enter:

```
library(zoo)
sub.as <- c(1, 0.75, 0.9, 0.475, 0.925, 0.975, 1, 1, 0.525, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 
 0.2, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.45, 0.875, 0.175, 0.15, 
 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 1)
fun <- (mean) # or fun <- mean
r2 <- rollapply(sub.as, width = 1, by = 1, FUN = fun, align = "left")
```

otherwise you could also convert your character like this:

```
fun = eval(parse("(mean)")), align = "left")
```

no matter how you do it, rollapply expects FUN as a closure

**EDIT**
@Roland is right, as the function (mean) does not exists as a proper function, and the function rollmean that is called internally can't be passed to rollapply directly, you need to implement a workaround. I did it like that, which might not be the most elegant way but it should work as you'd expect:

```
library(zoo)
my.func <- function(x, fun){
  if (deparse(substitute(fun)) == "mean") {
    result.vec <- rollapply(x, width = 1, by = 1, FUN = mean, align = "left")
  }
  else{
    result.vec <- rollapply(x, width = 1, by = 1, FUN = fun, align = "left") 
  }
  return(result.vec)
}
sub.as <- c(1, 0.75, 0.9, 0.475, 0.925, 0.975, 1, 1, 0.525, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 
            0.2, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.45, 0.875, 0.175, 0.15, 
            0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 1)
r1 <- my.func(sub.as, mean)
r2 <- my.func(sub.as, (mean))
r3 <- rollapply(sub.as, width = 1, by = 1, FUN = mean, align = "left")
r4 <- rollapply(sub.as, width = 1, by = 1, FUN = (mean), align = "left")
print(identical(r1,r2))
print(identical(r1,r3))
print(identical(r4,r2))
```

Comment: I've edited question can you please elaborate? Thank you.