# Comparing Character Vectors Per Row in R if Same True/False

Tags: r

I'm missing something very simple here.

I tried referring to [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374932/comparing-two-vectors-in-an-if-statement)

I'm trying to compare 2 character vectors to see if they equal each other on a per row basis, just expecting a `TRUE` / `FALSE` result per row.  (Trying to find the `FALSE`)

```
all(data.frame(dBase$process_name == dBase$import_process))
```

When I run the above I receive the result:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

I tried this as well but it seems to be overall, not per row.

```
identical(dBase$process_name, dBase$import_process)
```

So is there an alternative to comparing characters / strings to see if they are the same and pull up the rows were `FALSE` occurs?

Comment: remove the `all` and `data.frame`. `all` tests if all elements in a vector are `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dBase is the name of an existing data.frame, then you can do the following
to see all the rows where process_name and import_process are not identical.
Notice that I use the != to get only those where they are not equal.

```
dBase[ dBase$process_name != dBase$import_process, ]
```