# mean by group, excluding selected rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I'll take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group) old post as reference. So, the modified dataset looks like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(dive = factor(sample(c("dive1","dive2","dive3","dive4"), 14, replace=TRUE)),
                 speed = runif(14)
                 )
> df
     dive       speed
1  dive1 0.627296799
2  dive1 0.288594538
3  dive4 0.598177856
4  dive2 0.371158436
5  dive2 0.827468739
6  dive3 0.485977449
7  dive2 0.151295215
8  dive4 0.773988372
9  dive2 0.567155356
10 dive1 0.008585884
11 dive4 0.433648371
12 dive2 0.759196515
13 dive2 0.641193241
14 dive3 0.089451537
```

I would like to modify the column `speed` so that it contains the mean per group (same entry for each `.group`) for `dive1` and `dive2`, and do nothing (keep `df` as it is) for the other two groups).

I tried with `if` (and, of course, `group_by` and `summarise`), but that's not what I want, I receive a warning message and only 4 results...

```
df2 <- if(!(df$dive %in% c("dive3", "dive4"))){
  summarise(group_by(df, dive), speed = mean(speed))
} 

Warning message:
In if (!(df$dive %in% c("dive3", "dive4"))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> df2
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  dive  speed
  <fct> <dbl>
1 dive1 0.860
2 dive2 0.460
3 dive3 0.277
4 dive4 0.330
```

Comment: (1) It's a warning, not an error (though it'll become an error in R-4.3, I believe). (2) `if` requires always exactly length 1 (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/14170778/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10374932/3358272), but `df$dive %in% ...` is going to return a vector of length `nrow(df)`. If you intend that determination to be done within the `group_by` and `summarize`, then see the last code block in my answer. If that doesn't work, please add your expected output (as a literal frame object) in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah sorry, my bad, I edited with "warning message".

Comment: it's a common (and easy) thing to misinterpret one for the other, though some warnings _should_ be errors (and vice-versa, though more rare)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
df %>%
  group_by(dive) %>%
  mutate(speed = if (first(dive) %in% c("dive1", "dive2")) mean(speed) else speed) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 14 × 2
#    dive   speed
#    <fct>  <dbl>
#  1 dive4 0.548 
#  2 dive3 0.156 
#  3 dive4 0.207 
#  4 dive3 0.148 
#  5 dive4 0.886 
#  6 dive1 0.498 
#  7 dive3 0.690 
#  8 dive1 0.498 
#  9 dive4 0.0968
# 10 dive3 0.596 
# 11 dive2 0.447 
# 12 dive2 0.447 
# 13 dive3 0.859 
# 14 dive3 0.663
```

or perhaps a little shorter using

```r
df %>%
  mutate(speed = if (first(dive) %in% c("dive1", "dive2")) mean(speed) else speed,
         .by = dive)
```

If I misunderstood, and instead you want to *reduce* the two groups to a single row while keeping other groups as-is (not reduced), then perhaps:

```r
df %>%
  filter(dive %in% c("dive1", "dive2")) %>%
  summarize(speed = mean(speed), .by = dive) %>%
  bind_rows(filter(df, !dive %in% c("dive1", "dive2")))
#     dive     speed
# 1  dive1 0.4983562
# 2  dive2 0.4470575
# 3  dive4 0.5477776
# 4  dive3 0.1558491
# 5  dive4 0.2068528
# 6  dive3 0.1479428
# 7  dive4 0.8858552
# 8  dive3 0.6896862
# 9  dive4 0.0967569
# 10 dive3 0.5961494
# 11 dive3 0.8593978
# 12 dive3 0.6634452
```

Comment: Exactly this! I was looking for a way to use `if`and `mutate` indeed, but I could not understand how to do this!

Comment: Why do I need `first()`?

Comment: I see, because `if` takes conditions of length 1 only. This is quite counterintuitive, though.

Comment: You _could_ change `if (first(dive) %in% ...) ... else ...` into `ifelse(dive %in% c(..), mean(speed), speed)`, certainly. If you prefer that, go with it. It is more efficient and faster to do it with `if` here, since we know with certainty that `dive` is invariant within a group, so much easier to check just one instead of all of them.

Comment: Ohhh this is a great explanation, I'll remember this. Very very useful!