# In R, apply() throws quite a few warnings when applied over several columns. How relevant are these warnings?

Tags: r, apply

Please, consider the following MWE. I'm practicing a technique where I bind the results from several linear models to a data frame (tibble), then apply custom functions (here, grossly simplified for this MWE) to do some rounding/other modifications, then finally pass the tibble to flextable.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)

# Load example data
data("mtcars")

# Run linear models
model1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
model2 <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt, data = mtcars)

# Extract the statistics
coef_table1 <- summary(model1)$coefficients["hp", c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "Pr(>|t|)")]
coef_table2 <- summary(model2)$coefficients["hp", c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "Pr(>|t|)")]

# Combine results to matrix; then, convert to tibble
results <- rbind(coef_table1, coef_table2) %>% as_tibble()

# Name the models
results <- results %>% mutate(Model = c("Model1", "Model2")) %>% relocate(Model, .before = Estimate)

# Display results
results %>% flextable()
```

[image]

```r
# Create custom round function for statistics other that p-values
custom_round <- function(x) {
  case_when(
    x >= 0 && x < 0.01 ~ "<.01",
    TRUE ~ paste0(format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2))
  )
}

# Create custom function for p-values
custom_round_p <- function(x) {
  case_when(
    x >= 0 && x < 0.05 ~ "<.05",
    TRUE ~ paste0(format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2))
  )
}

# Apply the custom round functions to different sections of
# the results tibble with apply()
results_rounded <- bind_cols(results[1],
                      apply(results[2:3], 2, custom_round),
                      apply(results[4], 2, custom_round_p))

#> Warning in x >= 0 && x < 0.01: 'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

#> Warning in x >= 0 && x < 0.01: 'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

#> Warning in x >= 0 && x < 0.01: 'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
#> Warning in x >= 0 && x < 0.05: 'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

#> Warning in x >= 0 && x < 0.05: 'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

# Display rounded results
results_rounded %>% flextable()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-28 (except the flextable parts) with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The code works fine, but `apply()` throws the above warnings. How much are these of relevance in the usage depicted in this MWE?

Comment: Those are serious warnings that shouldn't be ignored.  They will be errors once you upgrade to R 4.3.0.  The problem is that you are using `&&` when you should be using `&`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14170778/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10374932/3358272

Comment: @user2554330, thank you for the comment, you are exactly right, `&&` was something of a typo that I didn't notice myself.

@r2evans, thank you for the comment; btw, were you suggesting by giving that link that `ifelse` should be used instead of `case_when`? The problem was caused by `&&`, and `case_when`doesn't seem to cause any errors/warnings. I prefer `case_when` over `ifelse` because I feel `case_when` is more human-readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related duplicate questions:

- `&` vs `&&`: [Difference between Boolean operators && and & and between || and | in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6558921/3358272)
- `'length(x) = 2 > 1'` (and *"'condition has length'"*): [Interpreting "condition has length > 1" warning from `if` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14170778/3358272), [Comparing two vectors in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10374932/3358272)

Fix your code by changing `&&` to `&`.

```r
custom_round <- function(x) {
  case_when(
    x >= 0 & x < 0.01 ~ "<.01",
    TRUE ~ paste0(format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2))
  )
}

# Create custom function for p-values
custom_round_p <- function(x) {
  case_when(
    x >= 0 & x < 0.05 ~ "<.05",
    TRUE ~ paste0(format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2))
  )
}
```

I also suggest using `mutate`/`across` instead of binding `apply` together.

```r
results %>%
  mutate(
    across(Estimate:`Std. Error`, custom_round),
    `Pr(>|t|)` = custom_round_p(`Pr(>|t|)`)
  )
# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#   Model  Estimate `Std. Error` `Pr(>|t|)`
#   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>        <chr>     
# 1 Model1 -0.07    0.01         <.05      
# 2 Model2 -0.03    <.01         <.05
```

Comment: Amazing, that `&&` was something of a typo that I had written into the code and reiterated in the second function; I "never" use `&&` intentionally. Big thanks for finding the error in the code - and moreover, optimizing the code elsewhere, too!