# Error in if, the condition has length > 1

Tags: r

I am still learning R and currently and practicing generating pizza plots. I keep receiving this error:

```
Error in if (0 <= angle & angle < 90) { : the condition has length > 1
```

What does this mean and what are some possible solutions? Thanks.

I have tried `ifelse(df <= 0, 0)` which produced another Error stating " 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double' "

Comment: (1) Never use `&` or `|` in an `if` statement unless it is wrapped in an aggregator such as `any` or `all`. (2) Don't know if `ifelse` is relevant, no idea what you're doing, but the `list` error hints at confused code. (3) This is possibly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14170778/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10374932/3358272. though the `ifelse(.)` hints at something else.

Comment: Welcome to SO, scrungebug! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: We can't know, because we don't know what "angle" is or what "df" is.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, it means that `if()` received a vector with more than one value. Example:

```
vector= 1:2
if(vector>1.5) {print("big")} else{print("small")
```

From a logical point of view, it also makes sense. `if()` is meant to return a single TRUE or a single FALSE which will dictate what pieces of code get executed. But if you give two values it does not know what to do. Is `(1,2)` bigger or smaller than `1.5`?

So to ask if a vector is greater or smaller than a number makes no sense.

But you hint at a similar operation that does make sense, `ifelse()`. This is an operation that is applying `if` for every element of `vector`.

```
result = ifelse(vector>1.5,"big","small")
```

is equivalent to:

```
result= character(2)
for(i in 1:length(vector) {
   if(vector[i]>1.5) {result[i]="big"} else{result[i]="small"}
}
```

Note that in this for loop we are running as many `if()` as there are elements in our vector and receiving as many results. So that is a different operation than `if(vector>1.5)` and a valid one.