# Cross-referencing columns in two data frames with different lengths

Tags: r, dataframe, text, iteration, cross-reference

New to R here, driving myself crazy trying to do something that I feel should be simple - thought I'd consult the hive mind before continuing to bang my head against my own limitations. Details:

Two dataframes (A and B) are created from different CSVs of different lengths. A has 221 rows, and B has 1355 rows. For troubleshooting purposes, dummy versions of these dataframes might look like these:

```r
A <- data.frame(Datasets = c("A", "B", "C"), in_B = c(NA, NA, NA))
B <- data.frame(Dataset = c("A", "B", "H", "D", "E", "F", "G"), irrelevent_column = NA)
```

The Datasets/Dataset fields above contain text - specifically, each record contains the name of a dataset within a database.

My goal is to iterate through A$Datasets to see if all of values in the Datasets column are also in B$Dataset. I'm looking for exact matches between entries, partial matches will give me a lot of false returns. I want to track this in A$in_B, writing "Yes" if there is a match and "No" if not. Based on the above example, the output should look like this:

```
      Datasets     in_B
1       A          Yes
2       B          Yes
3       C          No
```

I'm sure it's something silly that I'm missing, but I'm definitely struggling here - any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

My current (failed) attempt looks like this:

```r
    for (row in nrow(A)){
      if (A$Datasets %in% B$Dataset){
        A$in_B == "Yes"
      } else {
        A$in_B == "No"
      }
    }
```

Instead of getting the intended result above,m I got the following error:

```
**Error: the condition has length > 1**
```

I've also gotten the following error while attempting different approaches with the actual data, but not with the test example created above - I'm not sure why, and can't seem to replicate it with test data:

```
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: Have you tried the code that you gave us? `A <- as.data.frame(...)` for me errors with `Error: argument "x" is missing, with no default`. Did you mean just `data.frame` with no leading `as.`?

Comment: 'condition has length': https://stackoverflow.com/q/14170778/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10374932/3358272

Comment: Your sample data has no overlaps: `B` has no notion of `One`, `Two`, etc, it's just `A` through `G`. I think you're looking for `%in%`, though, perhaps `A$in_B <- ifelse(A$Datasets %in% B$Dataset, "Yes", "No")`? (Frankly, I prefer logical and not string, but that's me?)

Comment: Welcome to SO, JoeO! This is a good first question: it contains some sample data, code you've attempted, and some expected output. It is far better when the sample data can actually support the expected output, however.

Comment: Thanks for this! Post edited to rectify my silly mistake while making the example, appreciate you catching that. For the "as.data.frame" piece, I found the same - opted to simply use "data.frame() for the example as it worked for me here, but maybe it speaks to a greater issue with the data that I don't see

Comment: Realize that `if` conditionals must always be exactly length 1, never less never more. Also, R does well with whole vectors/columns at once, no need here for row-wise (`for` loop). Even if you do need to go row-wise, you loop over `row` _but never reference it_. You would actually need to do something like `if (A$Datasets[row] %in% B$Dataset) A$in_B[row] <- "Yes" else `A$in_B[row] <- "No".

Comment: Last pitch, `==` is a test for equality, never assignment; use `<-` or `=` (single) for assignment.

Comment: Great point about the vectors vs. row-wise approach - my primary coding experience is with python (though I'm still not a wizz), it's been somewhat of an adjustment coming to R. In any case, will take your advice and see if I can fix this thing!

Comment: Yes, python (and many languages) does much better with more literal `for` loops, R prefers vectorized operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems:

1. `==` is a test of equality, it can never be used for assignment. Use `<-` or `=`.
2. `if (cond) ...`, the `cond` must always be exactly length 1, never less never more. In an `if` statement, it is generally a single-value comparison (or such) that returns a single value, if you need to test with something that returns other than 1 then you need to aggregate it somehow, such as `all(..)` or `any(..)` or `sum(..)`, etc.
3. You have a row-wise loop using `row` as a variable *but you never reference `row`*. You should be referencing it inside your tests and assignments.
4. `row in nrow(A)` will only ever work on the last row, since `nrow(A)` returns a single number. If you want to iterate over all rows, then something like `1:nrow(A)` or `seq_len(nrow(A))` (the latter is better programmatically if `A` might have 0 rows, generally not a factor interactively).

If I fixed the `for`/`if` code literally (which I don't recommend), I might use

```r
for (row in seq_len(nrow(A))) {
  if (A$Datasets[row] %in% B$Dataset) {
    A$in_B[row] <- "Yes"
  } else {
    A$in_B[row] <- "No"
  }
}
```

But in the end, R will really perform much better here (and it might be easier to read and maintain as well) if you do things on a whole vector/column at a time.

```r
A$in_B <- A$Datasets %in% B$Dataset
```

This makes the column a `logical` one with `TRUE` and `FALSE`, I generally recommend those instead of `"Yes"`/`"No"` ... but those are also easy to use if you really prefer:

```r
A$in_B <- ifelse(A$Datasets %in% B$Dataset, "Yes", "No")
```

Comment: Or `c('No', 'Yes')[A$Datasets %in% B$Dataset + 1L]` instead of `ifelse()`.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to deal with that, thanks.